# Modularity in Caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have main project(wpf app) and "child" project(user control class library). I am trying to use user control from child project inside MainView of my main project:

MainView.xaml:

```
        <ContentControl  x:Name="ActiveItem" Grid.Column="1">

        </ContentControl>
```

MainViewModel:

```
        public void LoadAgenda()
        { 
            ActivateItem(new InstanceOfViewModelFromChildProject());
        }
```

And I get error

> "Cannot find view for InstanceOfViewModelFromChildProject".

I think I get this error because it tries to find view inside my main project and not in child project where this viewmodel and view are located. Is there anyway to fix this or another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Override the `SelectAssemblies()` method of the bootstrapper to return the assembly in which the views are defined.

From the [docs](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/bootstrapper):

> By default, the base class returns the assembly that your Application exists in:

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
{
    return new[] {
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    };
}
```

Comment: @Drasko: Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Override this methods in class that inherited bootstrapper class

```
        static Func<Type, DependencyObject, object, UIElement> _func;
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("YourAssemblyName"); // 
            AssemblySource.Instance.Add(assembly);

            _func = ViewLocator.LocateForModelType;
            ViewLocator.LocateForModelType = LocateForModelType;

        }

        private static Func<Type, DependencyObject, object, UIElement> LocateForModelType = (modelType, displayLocation, context) => {

            //use the default method first:
            UIElement view = _func(modelType, displayLocation, context);
            if (!(view is TextBlock))
                return view;

            var viewTypeName = modelType.Name.Replace("Model", string.Empty);
            var viewType = (from assmebly in AssemblySource.Instance
                            from type in assmebly.GetExportedTypes()
                            where type.Name == viewTypeName
                            select type).FirstOrDefault();

            return viewType == null ? new TextBlock { Text = string.Format("{0} not found.", viewTypeName) }
                : Activator.CreateInstance(viewType) as UIElement;
        };
```